# There is a problem with removing the comma and adding it back

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Ｑ：
Process: Originally, each number first removes the comma, then adds up, and then adds back the comma after adding up. The total amount of the first click is no problem (500,000,010), but the second click will become (500)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    goldOriginal: "10",
    items: [{
        goldAmout: "100,000,000"
      },
      {
        goldAmout: "100,000,000"
      },
      {
        goldAmout: "100,000,000"
      },
      {
        goldAmout: "100,000,000"
      },
      {
        goldAmout: "100,000,000"
      },
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    revert() {
      var goldItem = 0;
      var goldTotal = 0;
      for (let i in this.items) {
        let goldAmout = this.items[i].goldAmout;
        goldItem += parseInt(goldAmout.split(",").join(""));
        goldTotal = parseInt(this.goldOriginal) + parseInt(goldItem);
        this.items[i].goldAmout = 0;
      }
      this.goldOriginal = goldTotal.toLocaleString("en-US");
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>{{goldOriginal}}</span>
  <div class="revert-all text-center" @click="revert()">click</div>
  <div class="item-box" v-for="(item, i) in items" :key="i">
    <div class="amout-item d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="update-amout">{{ item.goldAmout }}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="amout-item d-flex justify-content-center">
      <div class="update-amout">{{ item.silverAmout }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are setting each amount zero here: `this.items[i].goldAmout = 0`

Comment: ... and `0` is not a string and as such, has no `split()` method

Answer (score 1):

You need to split your goldOriginal as well.

```
revert() {
    var goldItem = 0;
    var goldTotal = 0;
    for (let i in this.items) {
        let goldAmout = this.items[i].goldAmout;
        goldItem += parseInt(goldAmout.split(",").join(""));
        goldTotal = parseInt(this.goldOriginal.split(",").join("")) + parseInt(goldItem);
        this.items[i].goldAmout = "0";
    }
    this.goldOriginal = goldTotal.toLocaleString("en-US");
}
```

I find it kinda hard to understand so I made a shorter version

```
revert() {
    let goldTotal = parseInt(this.goldOriginal.split(",").join(""))
    for (let i in this.items) {
        let parsedGold = parseInt(this.items[i].goldAmout.split(",").join(""))
        goldTotal += parsedGold;
        this.items[i].goldAmout = "0";
    }
    this.goldOriginal = goldTotal.toLocaleString("en-US");
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- this.items[i].goldAmout = 0;
+ this.items[i].goldAmout = "0";
```